# Two metric space with same Cauchy sequences

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Question:
>
> If d,e are equivalent metrics on X, then $\left ( X,d \right )$ and $\left ( X,e \right )$ have the same Cauchy sequences.

I've first assumed to the contrary that the metric spaces have different Cauchy sequences.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: $d(u_n,u_p)\leq \alpha e(u_n,u_p)$.

Comment: It is probably easier to show this without contradiciton. Let $\langle x_n\rangle$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. Now what does this sequence need to satisfy to be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,e)$?

Comment: If $\forall \epsilon >0$, there exists $N\left ( \epsilon  \right ) \in \mathbb{N} $such that $d\left ( x_{m},x_{n} \right ) < \epsilon 
\forall m,n \geq N\left ( \epsilon  \right )$@MeesdeVries

Comment: Alright. What would make sense as a choice for $\epsilon$? Of course, you have to use the equivalence of the norms.

Comment: I am unsure how to make useful of the equivalence norm to determine a candidate for $\epsilon$...@MeesdeVries

Comment: @MeesdeVries In general, any $\epsilon > 0$ should work. How about leting $\epsilon=1$?
Recall that a convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence. If for any convergent sequence in the two metric space with the same limit, then they are the same Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I'm sorry. I say something silly. I should have said, what makes sense as a choice for $N$? Also, note that in general metric spaces, convergent sequences are not the same thing as Cauchy sequences; all convergent sequences are Cauchy, but not vice versa. When they *are* the same, the metric space is called complete.

Comment: Complete metric spaces are not relevant to this question. The question applies, for example, to the incomplete space $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the ordinary metric and any equivalent metric.

Answer (score 12):

This is false.

On $\mathbb R$ let $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $e(x,y)=|\tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}y|.$ Then $d$ and $e$ are equivalent, that is, they generate the same topology. But $(n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is an $e$-Cauchy sequence and not a $d$-Cauchy sequence.

What is true is that two metrics $d,e$ are equivalent iff they have the same convergent sequences. A convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence that has a limit point in the space. Note that $(n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in the example above, is an $e$-Cauchy sequence but it has no limit point in $\mathbb R.$

Metrics $d,e$ are called uniformly equivalent if and only if there exist positive $k_1,k_2$ with $k_1d(x,y)\leq e(x,y)\leq k_2 d(x,y)$ for all $x,y.$ Uniformly equivalent metrics are equivalent metrics,   and do have the same Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Does the converse to the original question hold? I.e. if two metric spaces (X,d) and (X,e) have the same Cauchy sequences, does it follow that $d \sim e$?

Comment: @SWdeVries.YES.  Let $(X,d)$ and $(X,e)$ have the same Cauchy sequences. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a $d$-Cauchy sequence, with $p\in X$ such that  with $ \lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,p)=0$. Let $y_{2n}=x_n$ and $y_{2n-1}=p.$  Then $(y_n)_n$ is a $d$-Cauchy  sequence so  $(y_n)_n$ is an $e$-Cauchy  sequence so $ \lim_{n\to \infty}e(y_{2n},p)=0.$ Now repeat with $d$ and $e$ interchanged . So $(X,d)$ and $(X,e)$ have the same convergent sequences so $d\sim e.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Can you please clarify why you had to construct $(y_n)_n$ in order to prove that $(x_n)_n$ is an $e$-Cauchy sequence? How does it follow that if $(y_n)_n$ is an $e$-Cauchy sequence then $(x_n)_n$ converges to $p$?

Comment: @sequence. As to why I had to: Maybe there is another method.... An $e$-Cauchy sequence in which infinitely many terms are equal to $p$  $must$  converge to $p$. This is true in $\Bbb R$. For a metric space it's the same except  we write $e(a,b)$ instead of $|a-b|.$

Comment: @DanielWainflee: You say, uniformly equivalent metrics cause the same Cauchy sequences. Is this sufficient condition also necessary?

Comment: @Thrash.  Uniformly equivalent metrics have the same Cauchy sequences.  But two equivalent metrics may have the same Cauchy sequences without being uniformly equivalent. If $e(x,y)=\min (1, d(x,y))$ then $d,e$ are equivalent and have the same Cauchy sequences, but if $d$ is unbounded then $d,e$ are not uniformly equivalent.  E.g. if $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ on $\Bbb R$....

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Does Uniformly equivalent metrics has same list of uniformly continuous functions?

Comment: @MeetPatel .Yes. Suppose $d_1$ and $d_2$ are metrics on $X$ and $k,k′>0$
 such that $kd_1(p,q)≤d_2(p,q)≤k′d_1(p,q)$ for all $p,q∈X.$ Suppose $(Y,e)$ is a metric space and $f: (X.d_1) \to Y$ is uniformly continuous. Given any $r>0$, there exists $s_1>0$ such that $d_1(p,q)<s_1\implies e(f(p),f(q))<r$ for all $p,q\in X. $ Now let $s_2=ks_1.$  We have $\forall p,q\in X\,[d_2(p,q)<s_2\implies d_1(p,q)\le (1/k)d_2(p,q)<(1/k)s_2=s_1\implies$ $\implies e(f(p),f(q))<r].$