# An example of equivalent metrics $d,d'$ and sequences $(x_n), (y_n)$ such that $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$ but $d' (x_n, y_n) \not \to 0$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $E$ be a set and $d,d'$ equivalent metrics on $E$, i.e., $d$ and $d'$ give rise to the same topology on $E$. Let $x_n, y_n \in E$ such that $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$. From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1997221/1019043), we have: Equivalent metrics have the same convergent sequences, but not Cauchy sequences. Then I guess it's **not** necessarily true that $d' (x_n, y_n) \to 0$.

Could you provide me with a counter-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the metrics $d'(x, y)=\lvert x-y \rvert$ and $d(x, y)=\lvert \arctan x - \arctan y\rvert$ on $\mathbb{R}$, which are described in the answer you quoted. Let $x_n=n$ and $y_n=n+1$. Then $d(x_n, y_n)\to 0$ (as both $\arctan(n)$ and $\arctan(n+1)$ converge to $\pi/2$), while $d'(x_n, y_n)=1$.